# how to create a debian package using "equivs-build" which can be "upgraded" if already installed?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, dpkg, version-control, equivs

I have created a `.deb` package using `equivs-build` command and providing necessary `control`, `preinst`, `postinst`, etc. I noticed that `version` can also be mentioned in `control` file. Now I want to create a `.deb` package with updated source code and I want to enable user to upgrade the package if it is already installed (and is of previous version, of course), as I won't be changing `conf` related files, etc. One way I can think of is to write a script which will first check for installed version, and will take actions accordingly (i.e. if installed, just update the source-code, database-migrations, etc. and if not, install the package using `dpkg -i <package-name>`). I was wondering if there was a way to achieve using `dpkg` only (something like `dpkg upgrade <package-name>`) which will handle installation or up-gradation as required.

Comment: On a side note, the `version` of the package usually isn't mentioned in `control` (unless you're declaring dependencies); it's only mentioned in `changelog`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 could you please elaborate a bit in details? As far as I know, mentioning `version` in `control` file is working. I tried mentioning different version in control file and tested installations. The package gets upgraded according to the `version` mentioned in `control` file. Am I missing out on something important here? Thanks.

Comment: See the [policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) here. Note that there is no `Version` field mentioned in the specifications for the source package control fields, which applies to source packages and the debian archive file; however, the `Version` field *is* required for binary package control fields (`DEBIAN/control`), which is the compiled package and the final deb. Instead, the version should be in `debian/changelog` (policy [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-dpkgchangelog)).

Comment: However, from what I can tell, you are directly changing the compiled debs, and so you might be fine.

Comment: I just looked at the `equivs-build` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/equivs-build.1.html), and based on what it does there, you are fine by using `Version` in the `control` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is indeed `dpkg -i`. This will install if not installed and upgrade if already installed. `dpkg` doesn't change user-modified configuration files.  It will ask you what to do about such cases (keep the modifications, discard the modifications, etc.) and it will always keep a backup of whatever you discard (the new config file provided by the package, or the old user-modified file ). Any file installed by the package in `/etc/` is considered by `dpkg` as a configuration file.

Comment: I went through this link: https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts and what I understood is I need to make changes to `prerm`, `postrm`, `preinst` and `postinst` scripts. But there are several cases shown (like `prerm upgrade` and `prerm remove` for `prerm`). How do I handle such cases? I mean, how can I separate the code for `upgrade` and `remove` in `prerm` itself?

Comment: @user2745266 Since `prerm` is a script, and usually a bash script, you can use [cases in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html). But you don't need to handle all the cases unless your install scripts (`postinst` and `preinst`) are doing complex stuff.